# WordPress - ERR_BAD_RESPONSE admin-ajax-php file upload

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, vue.js

I'm trying to upload files in WordPress using `admin-ajax.php`

I have this code in my functions.php file

```php
function upload_docs(){
 var_dump($_FILES);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_upload_docs', 'upload_docs');
add_action('wp_ajax_upload_docs', 'upload_docs');
```

The function at the moment is a test that I want to use to debug what information is passed from the front-end which is a Vue app hosted in a page template.

I've correctly loaded and localized the Vue CSS and js files and after the build, in my localhost, I'm able to pass the other forms I have configured on my functions file

On the front-end side, the Vue app has this method that will add the needed information to the WordPress backend

```js
sendUploadForm(){
 let documents = this.$refs.uploadedFiles.files
 let userData = new FormData()
 for(let i = 0; i < documents.length; i++ ){
  userData.append('file[]', documents[i])
 }
 userData.append('action', 'upload_docs')
 axios.post(wp_param.ajaxurl, userData).then( res => {
   console.log(res)
 }).catch( e => console.log(e) )
 
}
```

What is going wrong with the code? I will always get a 500 error status code `ERR_BAD_RESPONSE` and I don't know if the function is called because I'm unable to see any `var_dump` or `var_export` from PHP. I've tried to enable the debug in wp-config file but nothing changed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How did you enable debug in wp-config? You should be able to see all PHP errors and notices logged, by default, in a file called debug.log that is created in the root of the wp-content/ folder.

Comment: @Tami I've modified the value of the `WP_DEBUG` constant to true and the errors are logged on screen, but when the browser console log the 500 error, the errors from php will be the same, nothing added to the screen

Comment: Add these additional two lines under your WP_DEBUG one, make the error happen again, and check in the folder wp-content/ if you see a new file debug.log.

Comment: Sorry the constants to add are:

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

Comment: ok, need to test

Comment: Let me know?

On a different note, if I was building something to receive data to the backend, I would not use admin-ajax.php

I would definitely develop a custom REST endpoint.

Also always use nonces for security when passing data, and check permissions on your function to catch bad actors.

When working with an ajax request like this, you yes or yes need to terminate your function, you can use something like wp_die();

Comment: I'm testing now and I'll let you know. About the admin ajax, I want to use a custom endpoint but someone told me that isn't the best choice for this kind of operations?I need to have a custom registration/login form that is made using vue and have a wp backend

Comment: Yeah, I am giving you the same recommendation. You need to read this https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: @Tami I've tested your suggestion, in the log I see that the callback function I set will be not fired the error is `not found or invalid function name`. I need to investigate. I can't copy the log because it's on another pc

Comment: Solved the issue. Now I need to implement nonces and other validation stuff on other form fields. Thank you for the support. I will consider to use the rest api instead of admin ajax method

Comment: Cool! I will add this as an answer so you can accept it to help others, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these additional two lines under your `WP_DEBUG` one, make the error happen again, and check in the folder `wp-content/` if you see a new file `debug.log`.

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Consider:

- Implementing nonces and permission checks to protect your endpoints
- If only logged in users are supposed to be able to upload files, ensure the no_priv method is properly locked down
- Using a custom REST API endpoint instead of admin-ajax https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/
- Terminate your function with wp_die(); when using AJAX in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this problem because of WordPress plugin conflicts.

You can disable unused plugins and check.